# Task method returns TaskCanceledException was caught

Tags: c#, wpf, async-await

I am trying to make a call to a service, the service is supposed to return all the records but i am getting a TaskCancelledException with a message A Task was cancelled and then the results are null. I know there is lots of data (tried with small data and works fine). How can I make it so it continues working (keep grabbing records) without throwing the "A Task was cancelled". Here is my method

```
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> ObtainData(string url, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
{            
    Result<string> result = new Result<string>();
    try
    {
        HttpRequestMessage request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url);
        HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request); //HttpClient

        string jsonresult = await HandleReceipt(response, type);

        result.Result = jsonresult;
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        result.Message = "Problem obtaining data.";
    }

    return result;
}
```

I see there is a cancellation token being passed, is there a way to handle the cancellation?. Also, this method is being called from here:

```
public async void GetJsonData()
{
    string json = await ObtainData();
}
```

I would like it to complete getting the request without cancelling.

Comment: Does the request take time to complete?

Comment: Yes it does, works fine with small sets of data being requested. But with a bit more than that it gives me 'A Task was cancelled'

Comment: I will also have to add something like "loading" in the view while this is being done.. but this is like the first part of it.

Comment: it doesn't seem like your using your Cancellation token , from the method stub , i'm guessing it is another which you didn't declare maybe from the SendAsync ? 

Show the stack trace of the exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It sounds from your question and comments that your request is timing out. Try setting the [`HttpClient.Timeout`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient.timeout(v=vs.118).aspx) property

```
public async Task<ActionResult<string>> ObtainData(string url, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
{            
   Result<string> result = new Result<string>();
   try
   {
       var request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(url);
       request.Method = "GET";
       HttpResponseMessage response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request); //HttpClient
       httpClient.TimeOut = TimeSpan.MaxValue // change this as you like

       string jsonresult = await HandleReceipt(response, type);

       result.Result = jsonresult;
   } 
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
      result.Message = "Problem obtaining data.";
   }

   return result;
}
```

**Edit**

Regarding you comment about the exception, this is from MSDN:

> The Timeout property must be set before the GetRequestStream or GetResponse method is called.

Create a new instance of `HttpClient` before making the request, or set it inside the code where you initialize the client (constructor i assume).

Comment: Thank you Yuval, I added that line but, it says "This instance has already started one or more requests. Properties can only be modified before sending the first request.", i also moved the line above the request. But still get the same error. I think that httpclient is being used by a ping service or something like that.. so it sends a cancellation token somewhere.. is there a way to check  this?

Comment: Try setting a new instance of `HttpClient`: `var client = new HttpClient` and use that to make your request

Comment: @ergwin Note i edited the creation of `HttpWebRequest` as i saw using [`new HttpWebRequest`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc190216(v=vs.110).aspx) is obsolete.

Answer (score 1):

As Yuval Itzchakov mentioned you should set the Timeout property to a larger value (but it is a TimeSpan not an integer) and you should use the cancellation token in the HTTP request call if you are using with the async pattern.
And there is no need to use a global HttpClient (as Yuval pointed out) esspecially in this heavy async method calling nightmare (additionally i don't see the reason why should call anything inside the ObtainData async).

```
    public async Task<ActionResult<string>> ObtainData(string url, CancellationToken ct = default(CancellationToken))
    {
        try
        {
            using (var httpClient = new HttpClient
            {
                Timeout = TimeSpan.MaxValue
            })
            {
                using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, url))
                {
                    using (var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request, ct))
                    {
                        return new ActionResult<string>()
                        {
                            Result = await HandleReceipt(response, type)
                        };
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            return new ActionResult<string>
            {
                Message = "Problem obtaining data. " + ex
            };
        }
    }
```